# jQuery $("#myComplexId").remove() not working with special characters vs doc.getElementById().remove() working just fine

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm using:

```
let idOfParentElement= "xd%63-3?',";
$(`#${idOfParentElement}`).remove();  //does not work
```

But when I use document get element by id method and remove it works just fine:

```
document.getElementById(`${idOfParentElement}`).remove();
```

Why isn't the jQuery method working with complex ids?

Comment: How is this evaluated? `${idOfParentElement}`

Comment: @SandeepNayak back ticks are template literals https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Have you try `$('#'+idOfParentElement).remove();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [jQuery docs of selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) :

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \. For example, an element with id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\.bar"). The W3C CSS specification contains the complete set of rules regarding valid CSS selectors. Also useful is the blog entry by Mathias Bynens on CSS character escape sequences for identifiers.

---

So you need to escape any metacharacter in the selector which has special meaning in jQuery. You can use [`jQuery.escapeSelector()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/) method for escaping those metacharacters(added in jQuery version 3).